# Calling stored procedure from Spring Data JPA with multiple params of type list

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to call a stored procedure which looks like this:

```
create or replace procedure my_stored_procedure(
   xIds bigint[],
   yIds bigint[]
)
```

I am trying to call from Spring Data JPA as follows:

```
@Query(value = "CALL my_stored_procedure(:xIds,:yIds);", nativeQuery = true)
void deleteArchivedAgents(List<Long> xIds, List<Long> yIds);
```

It is giving me an error: `ERROR: procedure my_stored_procedure(bigint, bigint, bigint, bigint) does not exist. Hint: No procedure matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

I know that the corresponding data type for `long` in postgresql is `bigint`. Not sure how to cast the long data type in java to bigint in postgresql.

Note: The reason it is saying that `procedure my_stored_procedure(bigint, bigint, bigint, bigint) does not exist` is because each list has data of size 2.

Any help is appreciated.